# nonlinear ODE initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

A student came to me with a problem I couldn't solve.  It's the beginning of the semester in his Intro DiffEq class, and so the solution *shouldn't* be too difficult.  But it completely stumped me, and now I can't let it go!  Here it is:

**Problem.**  Find all solutions to the IVP:
$$
\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-4x^2}=\sqrt{x^4-y^2},\;\;\;\;y(0)=0.
$$
I thought about maybe just doing a sort of guess-and-check method, but the existence/uniqueness theorem doesn't apply, so I'm not sure that would help even if I could find a single solution, which I cannot in any case.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is not exactly an ODE, if you square both sides you end up with ${dy \over dx} = \pm \sqrt{ 4x^2+x^4-y^2}$, which describes two differential equations. (Well, one is a time reversal of the other.) Does not have a unique solution starting from $0$.

Comment: FWIW $y=x^2$ works.

Comment: And of course $y=-x^2$. Also, $|y|\le x^2$ for the square root on the right to make sense, and likewise $|y'|\ge |2x|$  on the left.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this differential equation $y'^2+y^2=C$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409748/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation-y2y2-c)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that, by the statement of the equation, $y'(x)^2\geq4x^2$ and $x^2\geq{y(x)^2}.$ The former restriction is equivalent to $y'(x)\geq2x$ or $y'(x)\leq-2x.$ The latter restriction is equivalent to $-x^2\leq{y(x)}\leq{x^2}.$ Therefore, $$y'(x)=\pm\sqrt{x^4+4x^2-y(x)^2}$$ with the restrictions already specified. These are two equations of the form $$y'(x)=f[x,y(x)],$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$ Notice that if $y(x)=x^2,$ then $$\sqrt{x^4+4x^2-y(x)^2}=2|x|,$$ hence $y(x)=x^2$ solves the former equation for $x\gt0,$ and it solves the latter for $x\lt0.$ Meanwhile, $y(x)=-x^2$ solves the former equation for $x\lt0,$ and solves the latter for $x\gt0.$ Thus, the former equation is solved by $y(x)=x|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and the latter is solved by $y(x)=-x|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}.$ With this in mind, you should try $z(x)=|x|y(x),$ and work with this, to find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is almost a solution; there's one slight technical point below that I can't see how to justify.
2. This approach is almost certainly not the intended solution, given that the problem was assigned at the *start* of the course.

The key feature of this problem is that exhibits a Hamiltonian structure.  Using the symmetry in $x$, restrict to $x\geq0$.  By squaring and rearranging, $$y^2+(y')^2=(x^2)^2+(2x)^2\tag{1}$$

We can think about this more generally by considering the *nonlinear* "Hamiltonian" operator $$(Hf)(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$$  If $q(x)=x^2$, then (1) says that $Hy=Hq$.  Now, $H$ is clearly not injective; $H(-y)=Hy$.  It would be reasonable to conjecture that (assuming a reasonable initial condition) $H$ is 2-to-1.  Unfortunately, that conjecture is false!  When $Hy=1$ and $y(0)=1$, two solutions are $y=1$ and $y=\cos{x}$.  Conversely, when $Hy=s$ and $s$ vanishes at $x_0$, we must have not just $y(x_0)=0$, but also $y'(x_0)=0$.

To pin down the behavior of multiple solutions, suppose $Hy_1=Hy_2=s$.  Subtracting and applying difference of squares: $$(y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2)=-(y_1'-y_2')(y_1'+y_2')$$  $\{x:y_1(x)^2\neq y_2(x)^2\}$ is open, and so a union of intervals; fix some such interval $(a,b)$.  Since $x\geq0$, $a\neq-\infty$; suppose $b\neq\infty$ too.  Without loss of generality, $y_1(a)=y_2(a)$.  On $(a,b)$, $$-1=\frac{y_1'-y_2'}{y_1-y_2}\cdot\frac{y_1'+y_2'}{y_1+y_2}=(\ln{\!(y_1-y_2)})'(\ln{\!(y_1+y_2)})'$$  In particular, neither factor is infinite, so neither is $0$; by continuity, each factor has a consistent sign.  Thus their integrals are (strictly) monotonic on $(a,b)$.  Since $\ln$ is monotonic, we can drop it: $y_1-y_2$ must be strictly monotonic on $(a,b)$.  Since $y_1(a)-y_2(a)=0$, we cannot have $y_1(b)-y_2(b)=0$; instead, $y_1(b)=-y_2(b)$.

Thus there is an outer "envelope" solution $e$ to $Hy=s$; at particular points, other solutions might coincide with the envelope, and then "fall off" it and oscillate down to $-e$, where they rejoin the envelope.  In the $s=1$ case, $e=1$ and each half-cycle of $\cos$ is an oscillation; in (2), $q$ is the envelope.  Also, it might take infinite time for an oscillation to reach $-e$; we assumed above that $b<\infty$, and I think an example where $b=\infty$ occurs in \begin{gather*}
(Hy)(x)=\begin{cases}(H1)(x)&x\leq1\\(H\sqrt{\cdot})(x)&x\geq1\end{cases} \\
y(0)=1
\end{gather*}  In such circumstances we cannot conclude that $y$ is an envelope solution simply by noting that $y\geq0$; $y$ might instead be an oscillation that is less than half-complete when we reach $\infty$.

Nevertheless, I'm going to assume that the envelope solutions in (1) are $C^3$.  This is the one point I can't justify; it is certainly true if $q$ is in fact the envelope.

To get a better handle on the oscillations, consider the following "polar" decomposition: $$(y,y')=a(\sin{\theta},\cos{\theta})$$  (I believe physicists call these "action-angle coordinates.")  For that decomposition to hold, we must have the following two relations between $a\geq0$ and $\theta$: \begin{gather*}
a^2=e^2+(e')^2 \\
a\cos{\theta}=y'=a'\sin{\theta}-a\cos{\!(\theta)}\theta'
\end{gather*}

The second equation is much less nasty than it appears.  Dividing by $a\sin{\theta}$ and rearranging, we obtain the following ODE: $$\cot{\!(\theta)}(1-\theta')=\frac{a'}{a}=\ln{(a)}'=\frac{e'(e+e'')}{e^2+(e')^2}$$  Solving for $\theta'$, we have $$\theta'=1-\tan{\!(\theta)}\cdot\frac{e'(e+e'')}{e^2+(e')^2}\tag{2}$$  We've lost our initial condition, so temporarily impose $\theta(1)=c$.  Since $e\in C^3$, we can apply Picard-Lindelöf to conclude that (2) has a unique solution in $\theta$ except when $e^2+(e')^2=0$ or when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

To put this back into our original variables, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ corresponds to $(y,y')=(e,0)$.  But since $|y|\leq|e|$, the condition $(y,y')=(e,0)$ implies $e'=0$ or $e=0$.  If $e(x)=0$, then every solution to $Hy=s$ vanishes at $x$.  And $e'(x)=0$ implies that $s'(x)=0$.  In the case of (1), we see that the only point at which uniqueness might fail is $x=0$, when $e(x)=e'(x)=s(x)=s'(x)=0$.

It would thus seem that there are infinitely-many solutions to (1), corresponding to each choice of the initial condition $\theta(1)=c$.  *But this conclusion is premature!*  Picard-Lindelöf only gives us existence until $\theta(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k$.  And we want $\theta(x)$ well-defined for $x\in(0,\infty)$.  We know at least one initial condition gives a solution surviving on the full time interval $(0,1]$ — the solution corresponding to $q$.  (The other solution $-q$ produces the same initial condition because $\frac{y(1)}{y'(1)}=\tan{\theta(1)}=\frac{-y(1)}{-y'(1)}$.)  I claim that this initial condition is the only such.

The key property forcing every other solution to blow up is $a'\geq0$.  To see this, let $\theta_c$ solve (2) with the initial condition $\theta_c(1)=c$.  Pick $c_1>c_2\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$; suppose for contradiction both $\theta_{c_1}$ and $\theta_{c_2}$ survive to $x=0$.

Note that $$\theta_{c_1}(1)=c_1>c_2=\theta_{c_2}(1)$$  The two curves cannot cross unless uniqueness fails, which occurs at $x=0$ anyways.  So we might as well assume $\theta_{c_1}>\theta_{c_2}$ everywhere.  Now estimate the difference between the two curves: since $\tan$ is expansive, $$(\theta_{c_1}-\theta_{c_2})'=-(\tan{\!(\theta_{c_1})}-\tan{\theta_{c_2}})\cdot\frac{a'}{a}\leq-(\theta_{c_1}-\theta_{c_2})\cdot\frac{a'}{a}$$  Call $\Delta\theta=\theta_{c_1}-\theta_{c_2}$; then, rearranging, $$\frac{\Delta\theta'}{\Delta\theta}+\frac{a'}{a}\leq0$$  Integrating from $x$ to $1$, we have $$(\Delta\theta)(x)a(x)\geq(\Delta\theta)(1)a(1)=(c_1-c_2)a(1)$$  But in the case of (1), $a(0)=0$, whereas the right-hand-side is positive.  Thus $\lim_{x\to0^+}{(\Delta\theta)(x)}=\infty$, which can only occur if at least one of $\{\theta_{c_1},\theta_{c_2}\}$ crosses $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$.