# How to solve this differential equation $y'^2+y^2=C$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling to solve this differential equation

$$(y')^2+y^2=C$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. I have no idea how to proceed when $y'$ is squared.

Comment: Hint: differentiate it

Comment: Rewrite the DE as $\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\pm \sqrt {C-y^2}$ then separate and integrate

Comment: @user577215664 Thanks, that helped!

Comment: Be careful that you do not miss solutions like $y=\begin{cases}\sqrt{C}\cos(x)&x\geq0\\\sqrt{C}&x<0\end{cases}$ and $y=\begin{cases}-\sqrt{C}&x<-\pi/2\\\sqrt{C}\sin(x)&-\pi/2\leq x\leq\pi/2\\\sqrt{C}&x>\pi/2\end{cases}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan so this equation have multiple solutions?

Comment: @JimmyYang Most differential equations do. This one, squaring $y'$ has some complications if you seek to describe all solutions. Some naive attempts to solve this will only find solutions of the form $y=\sin(t+\varphi)$ and miss the potential to transition to a constant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$z=\frac{y}{\sqrt{C}},$$ so that $$(z')^2+z^2=1.$$ Hence $$z'=\sqrt{1-z^2}$$ or $$z'=-\sqrt{1-z^2}.$$ Here, the possible cases are that $z=-1,$ $z=1,$ or $-1\lt{z}\lt1.$ For the former two, the solution is already given by the cases themselves. For the latter, $$\frac{z'}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\pm1,$$ hence $$\int_0^t\frac{z'}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t=\pm{t}=\arcsin[z(t)]-\arcsin[z(0)],$$ hence $$z(t)=\sin(\arcsin[z(0)]\pm{t})=z(0)\cos(t)\pm\sqrt{1-z(0)^2}\sin(t)=z(0)\cos(t)+z'(0)\sin(t).$$ Hence $$y(t)=-\sqrt{C},$$ $$y(t)=\sqrt{C}[z(0)\cos(t)+z'(0)\sin(t)],$$ $$y(t)=\sqrt{C}.$$ Furthermore, you can have piecewise solutions that incorporate the three above. Remember that $1=\sin(\arcsin[z(0)]\pm{t})$ is solved by $$\arcsin[z(0)]\pm{t}=2m\pi+\frac{\pi}2,$$ hence $$t=\mp\arcsin[z(0)]\pm\left(2m\pi+\frac{\pi}2\right),$$ and an analogous solution exists for $-1=\sin(\arcsin[z(0)]\pm{t}),$ so at these points, you can branch off from a sinusoidal function to a constant function, and this gives you infinitely many solution families.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, for real functions $C<0$ is not possible.

For $C=0$ you can only get the zero function as solution.

For $C=R^2>0$ you can use polar coordinates of the pair $(y',y)$ to get $y=R\sin\phi(t)$, where then $y'=R\cos\phi(t)$ from the circle equation and at the same time $y'=R\cos\phi(t)·\phi'(t)$ as derivative of the first equation (at points where $y'\ne 0$, else $\phi$ need not be differentiable).

So either $\cos(\phi(t))=0$ or $\phi'(t)=1$, and one can switch from one condition to the other whenever $\cos(\phi(t))=0$.